# Finding a function that would produce these expansions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions

I have a function $f(a,b,c)$ that expands to the following as $c$ grows:

$f(a,b,1)=0$

$f(a,b,2)=\frac{1}{a}$

$f(a,b,3)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b-1}$

$f(a,b,4)=-\frac{2}{a}+\frac{1}{b-1}+\frac{4}{a-1}$

$f(a,b,5)=-\frac{2}{a}-\frac{2}{b-1}+\frac{4}{a-1}+\frac{4}{b-2}$

$f(a,b,6)=\frac{3}{a}-\frac{2}{b-1}-\frac{12}{a-1}+\frac{4}{b-2}+\frac{12}{a-2}$

$f(a,b,7)=\frac{3}{a}+\frac{3}{b-1}-\frac{12}{a-1}-\frac{12}{b-2}+\frac{12}{a-2}+\frac{12}{b-3}$

$f(a,b,8)=-\frac{4}{a}+\frac{3}{b-1}+\frac{24}{a-1}-\frac{12}{b-2}-\frac{48}{a-2}+\frac{12}{b-3}+\frac{32}{a-3}$

$f(a,b,9)=-\frac{4}{a}-\frac{4}{b-1}+\frac{24}{a-1}+\frac{24}{b-2}-\frac{48}{a-2}-\frac{48}{b-3}+\frac{32}{a-3}+\frac{32}{b-4}$

$f(a,b,10)=\frac{5}{a}-\frac{4}{b-1}-\frac{40}{a-1}+\frac{24}{b-2}+\frac{120}{a-2}-\frac{48}{b-3}-\frac{160}{a-3}+\frac{32}{b-4}+\frac{80}{a-4}$

$f(a,b,11)=\frac{5}{a}+\frac{5}{b-1}-\frac{40}{a-1}-\frac{40}{b-2}+\frac{120}{a-2}+\frac{120}{b-3}-\frac{160}{a-3}-\frac{160}{b-4}+\frac{80}{a-4}+\frac{80}{b-5}$

$f(a,b,12)=-\frac{6}{a}+\frac{5}{b-1}+\frac{60}{a-1}-\frac{40}{b-2}-\frac{240}{a-2}+\frac{120}{b-3}+\frac{480}{a-3}-\frac{160}{b-4}-\frac{480}{a-4}+\frac{80}{b-5}+\frac{192}{a-5}$

And so on. I want to find a function that produces the right expansion for any natural $c$.

What I have noticed in this function is:

1- When $c$ is odd, the terms alternate signs like ++--++... or --++--... while when its even it is the same thing but - ++--++... or + --++--...

2- The new term added when $c$ is even is $\frac{c2^\frac{c-4}{2}}{a-\frac{c-2}{2}}$, and when it is odd the numerator is the same as the previous one but with denominator $b-\frac{c-1}{2}$

3- The terms that change in $f(a,b,c)$ when compared to $f(a,b,c-1)$ when $c$ is even are only the ones with $a-x$ in the denominator, and when $c$ is odd only the ones with $b-x$ in the denominator

4- There seems to be some combinatorial properties to the sequences of coefficients but they seem to change for terms in each different denominator.

(EDIT) 5 - The expansion when $c$ is odd is easy if one knows the expansion for $c-1$, and for even $c$, the coefficients with denominator $a-x$ appear sequentially in the list http://oeis.org/A261356 (with some spaces in between sequences) . So that might be the way of generating the function.

I'm sure there must be some summation or something like that, that would produce these expansions so I ask for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(a,b,c) = g(a,\left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor ) + g(b - 1,\left\lfloor {\left( {c - 1} \right)/2} \right\rfloor 
$$

For $g$ we get the table reproduced here

[image: f(a,b,c)_1]

The diagonal values look to be
$$
d = \left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor  \cdot 2^{\,\left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor  - 1} 
$$
and taking the ratio of the terms in a column wrt the first non-null term in the same column 
we get the Pascal matrix shifted by one column to the left.

so it is easy to conclude that
$$
g(a,\left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor ) = \;\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor  - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor  - k - 1} \left( \matrix{
  \left\lfloor {c/2} \right\rfloor  \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right){{\left( {k + 1} \right) \cdot 2^{\,k} } \over {a - k}}} 
$$
at least within the terms that you gave.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only thing I can extract from this is that one can separate the function as "coefficients with $a-x$ as denominator", which go from $a$ to $a-\lfloor c/2 \rfloor -1$ and "coefficients with $b-x$ as denominator", which go from $b-1$ to $b- \lfloor (c-1)/2 \rfloor $, both of which I already pointed out. My challenge here is reproducing the sequence of numerators.

Comment: @Eduard: I have extended the hint